# udev change status displayed twice

Tags: ubuntu, udev

Every time, I run `udevadm monitor --udev` and insert a memory card to a card reader, `udev` displays triggers change rule twice with the same info. What should I do for it to display only once? Logs below:

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing    
UDEV  [7217.509229] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.3/5-1.3.4/5-1.3.4:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)    
UDEV  [7217.622353] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.3/5-1.3.4/5-1.3.4:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)
```